# How can a vertical scroll bar stay at the bottom when text is added continuously?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, append

I have a div and it has a scroll bar here is the code I've used:

```
<div style="width: 200px; height: 250px; overflow: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; -ms-overflow-x: hidden;" id="container"></div>
```

There will be more text added to the div but when the div does expand how can I have the vertical scroll bar remain at the bottom of the bar so the user can see the appended text?

Comment: Scroll to the bottom after adding? As long as you can guarantee you're not adding too much that you miss something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the `scrollTop` to `scrollHeight`, e.g.: http://jsfiddle.net/fAK2L/1/.

```
var div = $('div');
div.scrollTop( div.get(0).scrollHeight );
```

Comment: Well the only problem is, the div has a set height. I am appending text.

Comment: @Pete Allport: Sorry I was thinking wrong. You have to use `scrollHeight`: http://jsfiddle.net/fAK2L/1/.

Answer (score 1):

Use `element.scrollIntoView` for the last added element