# CSS Position list to bottom so last list item is visible

Tags: css

Wondering how I can position a list so the last item is always the first to be visible, I've positioned the list `absolute: bottom` but not sure how to make the contents scrollable, can anyone offer any suggestions? Is there a way of doing this with flex box? My problem is for the contents scroll I have to set `height: 100%` on `div.chat__inner`, this immediately jumps the list to the top.

**CSS**

```
    .chat {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.chat__inner {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

.messages {
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kyllle/jf2rvzag/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ny2L61z5/  I'll post an answer... this has a few commented lines of code due to getting the request of updated chat.

Comment: @styler check my answer which uses flex model as you have asked.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` to your messages container:

```
.chat__inner {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And a little javascript (jquery) from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7786014/how-can-a-vertical-scroll-bar-stay-at-the-bottom-when-text-is-added-continuously):

```
var div = $('.messages');
div.scrollTop(div.get(0).scrollHeight);
```

```js
var div = $('.messages');
div.scrollTop(div.get(0).scrollHeight);
```

```css
.chat {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.chat__inner {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.messages {
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chat">
  <div class="chat__inner">
    <div class="messages">
      <p>Message 1</p>
      <p>Message 2</p>
      <p>Message 3</p>
      <p>Message 4</p>
      <p>Message 5</p>
      <p>Message 6</p>
      <p>Message 7</p>
      <p>Message 8</p>
      <p>Message 9</p>
      <p>Message 10</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

slightly chagned your css:

```
.chat {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.chat__inner {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

.messages {
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jf2rvzag/1/

I don't think there is a good (if any) css solution because you will also have to take care of user actions.
Have a look at:
[Keep overflow div scrolled to bottom unless user scrolls up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614301/keep-overflow-div-scrolled-to-bottom-unless-user-scrolls-up)

I'm sure this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/ny2L61z5/

I've done this using Javascript / jQuery before, scrolling to the bottom when the page is loaded or updated:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var oldscrollHeight = $(".messages").prop("scrollHeight") - 20; 
  //Scroll height before the request

  //--make request here--
  var newscrollHeight = $(".messages").prop("scrollHeight") - 20; 
  //Scroll height after the request

  if (newscrollHeight > oldscrollHeight) {
    $(".messages").animate({ scrollTop: 100000 }, 'fast');
  }
})
```

EDIT:  I don't believe the .chat-inner class with position absolute is needed. And adding a defined height to your .messages class will allow scrolling:

```
.chat {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    overflow: hidden;
}


.messages {
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    height: 200px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are creating a chat application or something like that hence you want to display the last message always on the top.

You can can achieve this by using flex model.

Apply `display:flex;` to both `.chat__inner` and `.messages` and make `overflow-y: auto` for `.chat` so, that scrollbar will be displayed in case of overflow.

Along with this also set `flex-direction: column-reverse` in `.messages` to make the list appear in bottom to top fashion. You can see rest of the changes I have made in the code below.

```css
.chat {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.chat__inner {
     display:flex;
  }

.messages {
    position: relative;
    overflow:auto;
     -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    height: 100%;
     margin: auto;
     display:flex;
     flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat">
    <div class="chat__inner">
        <div class="messages">
            <p>Message 1</p>
            <p>Message 2</p>
            <p>Message 3</p>
            <p>Message 4</p>
            <p>Message 5</p>
            <p>Message 6</p>
            <p>Message 7</p>
            <p>Message 8</p>
            <p>Message 9</p>
            <p>Message 10</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```